# Url Rewrite Regex to Match Some Classic ASP Files (But not all)

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a bunch of old .asp files that I'm trying to redirect. I do not want to redirect all .asp files, just ones related to the "News" section.

**Examples:**
news_1-4-2009.asp
news_2-15-2008.asp
news.asp

I created a redirect rule that almost works:

```
<rule name="NewsRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*news(.*asp)?" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://www.example.com/about/newsroom" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The problem (as you might see) is that the action url is also a match and creates an infinite loop.

**Question**
I'm trying to say...
Any file that starts with "news" and ends in ".asp".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any file that starts with "news" and ends in ".asp".*

Give this a try:

```
^news.*\.asp$
```